# MQTT over SSL - thingsboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, thingsboard

I deployed thingsboard (latest version) in my kubernetes infrastructure, using GCP microservices tutorial (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/cluster/gcp-microservices-setup/).

The whole process went smoothly. Now, I want to activate the MQTT over SSL for device authentication.

For that, I looked at the link (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/mqtt-over-ssl) and tb-mqtt-transport.yml in thingsboard repository.

1. Genearate server self-signed PEM certificate and private key (server_key.pem + server.pem )

```
openssl ecparam -out server_key.pem -name secp256r1 -genkey
openssl req -new -key server_key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out server.pem
```

2. Create `tb-mqtts-config` config map and put the content of `server_key.pem`, `server.pem`
3. Uncomment entries on `tb-mqtt-transport.yml`

```
# Uncomment the following lines to enable two-way MQTTS
- name: tb-mqtts-config
  configMap:
    name: tb-mqtts-config
    items:
      - key: server
        path:  server.pem
      - key: server_key
        path: server_key.pem
```

4. Set variable environment on StatefulSet (tb-mqtt-transport)

```
# Uncomment the following lines to enable two-way MQTTS
- name: MQTT_SSL_ENABLED
  value: "true"
- name: MQTT_SSL_CREDENTIALS_TYPE
  value: "PEM"
- name: MQTT_SSL_PEM_CERT
  value: "/ssl-config/server.pem"
- name: MQTT_SSL_PEM_KEY
  value: "/ssl-config/server_key.pem"
```

5. The pods about `tb-mqtt-transport-0` works fine!
6. When testing connection with Validate Certificate + Encryption (tls) on MQTT Explorer, receive an error : "self signed certificate". I didn't load Server Certificate(CA) on MQTT Explorer.

[image]

As in the tutorial, my MQTT load balancer is a Service(LoadBalancer). I have a URL to get there (`mqtt.myurl.com`).

How can I generate keys + secret + CA for a domain to allow MQTT over SSL? It's easy and possible using GCP? Can anyone provide information about this?

**Edit 1**

I looked at this tutorial - https://arcwiki.rs.gsu.edu/en/ThingsBoard/DeviceCreation it's cool!
but how do I get "The tb-server-chain.pem certificate is generated at the server side"?